# Duplicity Centos 6 Error

Tags: centos, python, duplicity

I am trying to verify backup from ftp server using this command.

```
duplicity verify ftp://xxx.net@ftpback-bhs1-15.ip-198-100-151.net/ /home
```

I am getting this error

```
Difference found: File home/nginx has permissions 0:0 700, expected 500:500 700
Difference found: File home/nginx/domains has permissions 0:0 700, expected 500:500 755
Difference found: File home/nginx/domains/enxxxgd.com has permissions 0:0 700, expected 500:500 755
Difference found: File home/nginx/domains/enxxxgd.com/log has permissions 0:0 700, expected 500:500 755
python: ERROR: (rs_file_copy_cb) unexpected eof on fd417
python: ERROR: (rs_job_complete) patch job failed: unexpected end of input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1411, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1404, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1340, in main
    verify(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 757, in verify
    for backup_ropath, current_path in collated:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/duplicity/diffdir.py", line 269, in collate2iters
    relem1 = riter1.next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 499, in integrate_patch_iters
    final_ropath = patch_seq2ropath( normalize_ps( patch_seq ) )
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/duplicity/patchdir.py", line 479, in patch_seq2ropath
    misc.copyfileobj( current_file, tempfp )
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/duplicity/misc.py", line 166, in copyfileobj
    buf = infp.read(blocksize)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/duplicity/librsync.py", line 80, in read
    self._add_to_outbuf_once()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/duplicity/librsync.py", line 94, in _add_to_outbuf_once
    raise librsyncError(str(e))
librsyncError: librsync error 103 while in patch cycle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with Duplicity:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/662442

That thread included a couple of workarounds such as running the verify on single directories at a time vs. the entire tree. Not ideal but better than nothing.